# Want to map pin with title from another view controller in google map sdk on button click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a detailviewcontroller in which i have an imageview, a textfield,a textview and save button on navigation bar. Now when i fill the details and click on the save button, it should mark a map pin on map in the first controller i.e Homeviewcontroller. dont know where i am wrong

my storyboard image:
[image: storyboard image]

Some code that i have tried..

My HomeViewcontroller.swift file:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import CoreLocation

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{

    var arrData = [[String:Any]]()

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapCenterPinImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tabBar: UITabBar!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var zoom: Float = 15

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.settings.compassButton = true
        tabBar.delegate = self

    }


    func pinMarker()
    {
        if self.arrData.count != 0
        {
            mapView.clear()
            for item in self.arrData {
                let data = item as NSDictionary
                mapView.delegate = self
                if let lat = data.value(forKey: "lati") as? Double, let lng = data.value(forKey: "longi") as? Double
                {

                    let places: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat,lng)

                    let marker_places = GMSMarker(position: places)
                    marker_places.title = (data.value(forKey: "title") as! String)
                    marker_places.map = mapView
                }
            }
        }


    }


    @IBAction func imgPickerBtn(_ sender: Any) {

        if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera))
        {
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.allowsEditing = true
            picker.sourceType = .camera
            self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            let picker = UIImagePickerController()
            picker.delegate = self
            picker.allowsEditing = true
            picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tabBar.selectedItem = self.tabBar.items?.first

        let data = Defaults[.userDataResult]
        self.arrData = data as! [[String:Any]]
        print(self.arrData)
        self.pinMarker()

    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        if let pickedImg = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            let objDetailVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController") as! DetailsViewController
            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                objDetailVC.transferedImage = pickedImg
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objDetailVC, animated: true)
            }
    }


    @IBAction func ZoomInBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        zoom = zoom + 1
        self.mapView.animate(toZoom: zoom)
    }

    @IBAction func zoomOutBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        zoom = zoom - 1
        self.mapView.animate(toZoom: zoom)
    }

}
extension HomeViewController:  UITabBarDelegate {
    func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

        //This method will be called when user changes tab.
        if tabBar.selectedItem?.tag == 2 {
            print("tag=2")
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListTableViewController") as! ListTableViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
        }
    }
}

//MARK: CLLocationManager Delegate
extension HomeViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        guard status == .authorizedWhenInUse else {
            return
        }

        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location: CLLocation = locations.last!
        print("Location: \(location)")

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: location.coordinate.latitude,
                                              longitude: location.coordinate.longitude,
                                              zoom: zoom)

        if mapView.isHidden {
            mapView.isHidden = false
            mapView.camera = camera
        } else {
            mapView.animate(to: camera)
        }


    }

    // Handle location manager errors.
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

my detailviewcontroller.swift file:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import CoreLocation


class DetailsViewController: UIViewController{

    var picker : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

    @IBOutlet weak var selectedDate: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailsVCImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var geoAddressLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var notesTextView: UITextView!


    var imgPath = String()
    var imgname  = String()

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var currentLatitude = Double()
    var currentLongitude = Double()

    var mapView:GMSMapView!
    var transferedImage:UIImage!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        notesTextView.text = "Enter Notes here...."
        notesTextView.textColor = .lightGray
        notesTextView.returnKeyType = .done

        detailsVCImage.image = transferedImage

        hideKeyboardWhenTapped()

        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 15,height: self.titleTF.frame.height))
        titleTF.leftView = paddingView
        titleTF.leftViewMode = .always



    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func currentDate() -> String {
        let date = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy_HH:mm:ss"
        let result = formatter.string(from: date)
        return result
    }

    func saveImg(image: UIImage) {

        let documentsDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let iname = currentDate()
        let fileName = "\(iname)"+".png"
        let jpgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(detailsVCImage.image!, 1.0)
        let fileurl = documentsDir.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileurl.path) {
            do {

                try jpgData?.write(to: fileurl)
                print("Image Added Successfully")
                print(fileurl)
                imgname = fileName

                let data = Defaults[.userDataResult]
                print(data)
                var userFinalArray = [[String:Any]]()
                var userTempArray = [[String:Any]]()

                if data.count != 0 {

                    userTempArray = data as! [[String:Any]]
                    var obj = [String:Any]()
                    obj["title"] = self.titleTF.text
                    obj["notes"] = self.notesTextView.text
                    obj["image"] = self.imgname
                    obj["date"] = Date().string(format: "dd.MM.yyyy")
                    obj["lati"] = currentLatitude
                    obj["longi"] = currentLongitude
                    userTempArray.append(obj)
                }else {
                    userTempArray = data as! [[String:Any]]
                    var obj = [String:Any]()
                    obj["title"] = self.titleTF.text
                    obj["notes"] = self.notesTextView.text
                    obj["image"] = self.imgname
                    obj["date"] = Date().string(format: "dd.MM.yyyy")
                    obj["lati"] = currentLatitude
                    obj["longi"] = currentLongitude
                    userTempArray.append(obj)
                }

                userFinalArray = userTempArray
                Defaults[.userDataResult] = userFinalArray


                let dataArr = Defaults[.userDataResult]
                print(dataArr)

            } catch {
                print("error saving file", error)
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func datePickerTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        picker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.dateAndTime
        picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dueDateChanged(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
//        self.picker = UIDatePicker(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 85))

        let pickerSize : CGSize = picker.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero)
        picker.frame = CGRect(x:0.0, y:442, width:pickerSize.width, height:85)
        //width: 288
        self.view.addSubview(picker)

    }

    @objc func dueDateChanged(sender:UIDatePicker){
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        selectedDate.setTitle(dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date), for: .normal)

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        picker.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    @IBAction func saveDataTaopped(_ sender: Any) {

       print("Store data in user Default")
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
       saveImg(image: self.transferedImage)

    }

    func reverseGeocodeCoordinate(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()

        geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) { response, error in
            //            self.geoAddressLabel.unlock()


            guard let address = response?.firstResult(), let lines = address.lines else {
                return
            }

            self.geoAddressLabel.text = lines.joined(separator: "\n")

        }

    }


    @IBAction func getLocationAddress(_ sender: Any) {
//        reverseGeocodeCoordinate(target)

    }
}

extension DetailsViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func hideKeyboardWhenTapped () {
        let tap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(DetailsViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}

extension DetailsViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
//        reverseGeocodeCoordinate(position.target)
    }

//    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, willMove gesture: Bool) {
//        geoAddressLabel.lock()
//        
//        if (gesture) {
//            mapCenterPinImage.fadeIn(0.25)
//            mapView.selectedMarker = nil
//        }
//    }

}

extension DetailsViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.text == "Enter Notes here...." {
            textView.text = ""
            textView.textColor = .black
        }
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if text == "\n" {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.text == ""  {
            textView.text = "Enter Notes here...."
            textView.textColor = .lightGray
        }
    }
}

extension DetailsViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        guard status == .authorizedWhenInUse else {
            return
        }

        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location: CLLocation = locations.last!
        print("Location: \(location)")

        currentLatitude = location.coordinate.latitude
        currentLongitude = location.coordinate.longitude
        print(currentLongitude)
        print(currentLatitude)

    }

    // Handle location manager errors.
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
}

extension Date {
    func string(format: String) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need to show your whole code just be specific about problem

Comment: when click on save button in detailsviewcontroller file, pin marker should be mapped on map with current location and with title when we click on marker

Comment: please help me with it

Comment: Do you want when you click the button the controller goes to HomeViewController and show the pin in your current location?

Comment: no when i click save button

Comment: I mean when you click save button you want to show the pin on current location

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192302/discussion-between-nishant-narola-and-wings).